# Limiting TCP connections

Tags: terminal, internet, network, tcp

How can I limit TCP connections on Mac using Terminal?

I used iptables on Linux (eOS) to limit the connections of an application (Ace Stream Player) as follows:

```
$iptables -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 50/s -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Then I started the application and typed:

```
$iptables -R OUTPUT 3 -p tcp -j DROP
```

If there is a similar program on Mac, how would these lines look like?